# Is it true that the roots of a real multivariate polynomial depend continuously on its coefficients?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I'm studying polynomials and wondering if it is true that the roots of a *multivariate* polynomial depend continuously on its coefficients?

I have seen this kind of result for "univariate" polynomials with "complex" coefficients but not aware of any generalization to the multivariate and real cases.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "depend continuously?" The set of roots of a multivariate polynomial is usually uncountable, so it's not so clear how to identify a root in a perturbation with a root in the original.

Comment: what i meant is that the roots can be shown as smooth functions of the coefficients. in particular, if the coefficients are slightly perturbed then the roots should vary slightly.

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of the function?

Comment: for univariate case, the polynomial $P:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ and

Comment: for multivariate case, the polynomial $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ goes from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ with complex coefficients. In case of real polynomials, both coefficients and roots are real numbers.

Comment: Within the constraints of [Implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) the answer (to a suitably refined question) is **Yes**. As long as we are not in the vicinity of a critical point, the dependence of zeros on the coefficients is smooth. If you work over a field other than reals or complex numbers, then you need to specify what you mean by "continuous". The etale topology was described to me (by someone who knows) as the coarsest topology over which the IFT holds.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: thanks for the hint. as I'm not familiar with this topic, could you provide me some literature on the multivariate case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really make much sense of this over $\mathbb{R}$ even in the univariate case because there may not even be roots.  For instance, consider the polynomial
$$x^2 + C$$
For $C \leq 0$ there are roots; for $C > 0$ there are not.  What would it mean for the roots to "vary continuously" here?

Also, multivariate polynomials don't have a discrete set of "roots" the way univariate polynomials do.  They cut out an *algebraic hypersurface*.  For instance, consider the zeroes of the polynomial $x^3 - y^3 + x^2 + C$ for various values of C:

[image] [image] [image]

(images courtesy Wolfram|Alpha)

What does it mean for these to "vary continuously"?

Comment: The question is not completely nonsensical, and the answer is probably yes, at least over the complex numbers. The question is: what is the right question?

Comment: @Daniel McLaury You are perfectly right. Sorry for the inapropriate comment that I erase for future readers.